# Unable yo customize wordpress page because I supplied an invalid argument somewhere

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a wordpress theme to build up my website. It seems that the script of front page cannot be changed manually but through customization gui provided by wordpress only. 
In a space where we could provide url, I, out of curiosity, provided **target="_blank"** inside the space only.
That means, this is included inside the quotes ("") of href now.
Now the whole section is invisible from the page. Insted, on oage the following error shows up:
**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /srv/disk13/2065318/www/designyourspace.co/wp-content/themes/Parallax-One/functions.php on line 858**
How to amend it???
Please help.

Comment: Please provide the code of that file/lines...

Comment: /*Check if Repeater is empty*/
function parallax_one_general_repeater_is_empty($parallax_one_arr){
 $parallax_one_services_decoded = json_decode($parallax_one_arr);
 foreach($parallax_one_services_decoded as $parallax_box){
  if(!empty($parallax_box->choice) && $parallax_box->choice == 'parallax_none'){
   $parallax_box->icon_value = '';
   $parallax_box->image_url = '';
  }
  foreach ($parallax_box as $key => $value){
   if(!empty($value) && $key!='choice' && $key!='id' && ($value!='No Icon' && $key=='icon_value') ) {
    return false;
   }
  }
 }
 return true;
}

Comment: New ques to the same problem in case you need for reference,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35861649/error-in-webpage-due-to-some-code-bug